# ASP.NET - VB.NET - Retrieving record from MS-Access database

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to retrieve record data from an MS-Access database and store it into a variable.

I'm using this SQL command to query the database:

```
Dim cmdRead As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT UserID FROM [User] where Username=?", conn)
```

How do I do it in VB.NET to read data from the UserID column (in the db) and store it into a variable in VB.NET?

What I basically want to do is to retrieve the UserID so that I can then retrieve the Name and Surname of the user from the same table.

Note: I'm using ASP.NET with Web Develop 2003 and an MS-Access 2003 db.

This is the full code:

```
  Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite3\db.mdb;")


        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT Username, Password FROM [User] where Username=? and Password=?", conn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text)


        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim read As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If read.HasRows Then
                While read.Read()
                    If txtUsername.Text = read.Item("username").ToString And txtPassword.Text = read.Item("password").ToString Then

                        Dim tID As Long = read.Item("UserID").ToString
                        Dim tName As String = read.Item("CustomerName").ToString
                        Dim tSurname As String = read.Item("CustomerSurname").ToString

                        lblLogged.Text = lblLogged.Text + tName + tSurname

                        lblLogged.Visible = True
                    End If
                End While
            Else
                lblLogged.Text = "Login unsuccessful"
            End If

            read.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message())

        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Are you currently getting an error?

Comment: No, No. It's working fine. What I want is to add code to retrieve the UserID, Name and Surname, not insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should go in your Try block

```
conn.Open()             
Dim read As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()             
If read.HasRows Then              
    While read.Read()             
        If txtUsername.Text = read.Item("username").ToString And txtPassword.Text = read.Item("password").ToString Then                
            Dim tID as long = read.Item("UserID").ToString
        Else                 
            lblLogged.Text = "Login unsuccessful"             
        End If   
    End While           
End If
```

And in the Finally block

```
read.Close()
```

Comment: The code to read the fields has to go within the .HasRows if statement, and then you need a loop to run through the records.  If you find it, it assigns the UserID field to the variable tID (declared locally here, but you would want it at Class level, or just assign it to a field somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Something is out of order in your example. Please try this.

First change the OleDbCommand to retrieve also the userID, no need for a second command when your read from the same table and I suppose that UserName and Password identify an unique user

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT UserID, Username, Password FROM [User] where Username=? and Password=?", conn)
```

then add your parameters and query the database

```
Try             
     conn.Open()
     Dim read As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()             
     If read.HasRows Then              
         read.Read()
         ' Now you can read the Item and pass the values to your textboxes             
         txtUsername.Text = read.Item("username").ToString 
         txtPassword.Text = read.Item("password").ToString 
         txtUserID.Text = read.Item("userid").ToString  
     Else                 
          lblLogged.Text = "Login unsuccessful"             
     End If              
     read.Close()         
Catch ex As Exception             
     Response.Write(ex.Message())          
Finally             
     conn.Close()         
 End Try
```

Comment: Sorry had removed them by mistake!

Comment: How do I get data from a table tough? from UserID, Name and Surname?

Comment: Hey tanks for the code. I updated the code to show you what I've done so far. What I meant is that if the username is "jdoe" a VB SQL query would search for the UserID matching "jdoe" and from the table retrieves the Name and Surname. I updated the code I made so far but all the lblLogged.Text inputs is "UserID" when I try to "login"

Comment: You can only read the columns you put in your select statement. If this columns are on the same table 'User' all you have to do is to change the `SELECT UserID, CustomerName, CustomerSurName ..... etc`